# Installing a Windows 98/95 Keyboard Driver on Windows 10

Tags: drivers, windows-10

I have a keyboard that I really like, but the driver (http://www.driverguide.com/driver/detail.php?driverid=20378) is only for Windows 95/98. I am running Windows 10.

I followed the tutorial here 
http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/15523-compatibility-mode-settings-apps-change-windows-10-a.html

by edit the registry value of the executable to `~ RUNASADMIN WIN95` but that doesn't work either.

Am I out of luck?

Comment: What makes you think the keyboard needs anything more then the default driver?  Are we talking about a PS/2 or USB keyboard?

Comment: PS/2 keyboard. Didn't work right off the bat when I plugged it in, so I thought it might be a driver issue.

Comment: Windows 95/98 drivers do not work in Windows 10.

Comment: Strangely enough, Windows doesn't detect any PS2 devices in the Device Manager. Does that mean the keyboard is broken / PS2 interface is not working properly?

Comment: Get hold of a PS2 > USB converter. 50p from your local computer shop.

Comment: a $5 PS2 > USB converter worked fabulously. thanks